# Strapi showing status rather than welcome page

Tags: deployment, heroku-postgres, strapi

I am following Strapi documentation -deployment to heroku, react app (https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#heroku) using using PostgreSQL.
I receive "Build succeeded" & "deployed" but when I open the app I reach this page -[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaCkA.png) 
and not the Strapi welcome page to set-up my admin.

Comment: It's normal, that the production view of the index.html page `/`

Answer (score 0):

Open that link and add /admin at the end, press enter...then create your admin account to login.